# Make dict comprehension return by reference

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

- I have following dictionary: `original = {a:1, b:2}`
- I then run dict comprehension: `extracted = {k:v for (k,v) in original.items() if k == 'a'}`
- The following dict is returned: `{a:1}`
- If I mutate `extracted['a'] = 2`, `original['a']` will still be equal to `1`

### Question:

Is there a way to make the above dict comprehension return by reference? For example `extracted['a'] = 2` would result in `original['a'] = 2`.

I would prefer not to involve alteration of the `original` dictionary.

Comment: Short answer: No. (Not without changing your datatypes, anyhow -- if `extracted['a']` and `original['a']` were both lists, *then* you could make them be the same object).

Comment: ...if you **really** wanted spooky action at a distance, I suppose you could implement your own `dict`-like object that would know about the original and update it on `__setitem__()`. But this would break peoples' expectations about your code, and otherwise be a Bad Idea.

Comment: Thinking about Python's datamodel in terms of the datamodel of C-like languages is rarely fruitful. So forget about the "by reference" stuff.  For further info on this topic, please see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: OTOH, if you make those dict values mutable, then you can mutate them, rather than assign to them. Eg, `original = {'a':[1], 'b':[2]}; extracted = {k:v for k,v in original.items() if k == 'a'}; extracted['a'][0] = 3; print(original)` prints `{'a': [3], 'b': [2]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intended goal (of having a dictionary which, when updated, will also change the other dictionary from which it was derived) *can* be done even with immutable values, if your new dictionary is of a custom type with the desired logic added:

```
class MappedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, orig, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__orig = orig
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.__orig[k] = v
        return dict.__setitem__(self, k, v)

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
md = MappedDict(d, {k: v*2 for (k,v) in d.items()})
md['a']=5
```

...will leave both `d` and `md` having `'a'` having the value `5`, whereas `b` will differ (being `2` in the former and `4` in the latter).

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit", I seem to recall [someone saying](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). :)

Comment: But in case you use a conditional comprehension like in the question `{k:v for (k,v) in original.items() if k == 'a'}` and you alter the `md['b']` that would propagate to the original even though `md` didn't have a `b` element (by definition it was excluded). I'm not sure that's unwanted or wanted, I just wanted to mention this. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, comprehensions *always* return a shallow copy (well, actually it's a new object containing references to the values you iterate over). However it's only a shallow copy, so if you use mutable types as values and you change them in-place the change will propagate to the original object.

```
>>> original = {'a':[], 'b':[]}
>>> extracted = {k:v for (k,v) in original.items() if k == 'a'}
>>> extracted['a'].append(1)  # change one value in extracted in-place
>>> original                  # original also changed
{'a': [1], 'b': []}
>>> extracted
{'a': [1]}
```